# Constructing JSON

Tags: json, marklogic

My document is in XML and I need to construct a JSON format based on this document. First I created a query returning the right XML structure but when I convert this query to return JSON, I have a For Return problem.

```
Error: [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNDVAR: (err:XPST0008) Undefined variable $cat
```

---

**Original query:**

```
let $tree :=
<tree>{for $cat in distinct-values($doc//ns:category/@name)
    return <cat name="{$cat}">
    { for $var in $doc//ns:category[@name = $cat]//ns:variable/@name
      return <var name="{$var}"> 
      }  
      </var>
    }
    </cat>

  }
</tree>

return $tree
```

---

**Data:**

```
<category name="Catname">
  <variable name="Varname">
    <segment name="Seg1">9</segment>
    <segment name="Seg2">33</segment>
    <segment name="Seg3">32</segment>
    <segment name="Seg4">22</segment>
  </variable>
  <variable name="Vartwo">
    <segment name="Seg2one">1</segment>
    <segment name="Seg2two">2</segment>
  </variable>
</category>
<category> ....
```

---

**New Query:**

```
let $tree := 
json:array(
<json:array xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<json:value xsi:type="xs:string">
  {for $cat in distinct-values($doc//ns:category/@name) return $cat}
</json:value>
  <json:array>
    {for $var in $doc//ns:category[@name = $cat]//ns:variable/@name return $var}
  </json:array>
</json:array>          
)

return $tree
```

---

**Expected Output**

```
{"Catname": ["Varname": ["Seg1", "Seg2", "Seg3"], "Vartwo": ["Seg2one", "Seg2two"]]},
{"Cat2" ... }
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON output that you would like to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because the variable `$cat` is not in scope inside of the nested `<json:array/>` element. It's defined in the previous scope, and, therefore, not available.

<del>I'm not sure what JSON structure you want to create, but</del> it's definitely awkward to use that XML serialization to create JSON. I prefer an approach like this:

**Update:** The provided JSON structure isn't valid; I've taken the liberty of converting the category property to an object. These XQuery samples will output JSON as follows:

```
{"Catname":{"Vartwo":["Seg2one","Seg2two"], "Varname":["Seg1","Seg2","Seg3","Seg4"]}}
```

This approach uses the functional maps API:

```
let $map :=
  map:new(
    for $cat in distinct-values($doc//ns:category/@name)
    return
      map:entry($cat,
        for $var in $doc//ns:category[@name = $cat]//ns:variable
        let $name := $var/@name/fn:string()
        return map:entry($name, json:to-array($var/ns:segment/@name/fn:string())) ))
return xdmp:to-json($map)
```

And here's the same code, using the procedural maps API:

```
let $map := map:map()
let $_ :=
  for $cat in distinct-values($doc//ns:category/@name)
  let $cat-map := map:map()
  let $_ :=
    for $var in $doc//ns:category[@name = $cat]//ns:variable
    let $name := $var/@name/fn:string()
    return map:put($cat-map, $name, json:to-array($var/ns:segment/@name/fn:string()))
  return map:put($map, $cat, $cat-map)
return xdmp:to-json($map)
```

The key takeaways from this approach are

- construct arrays from XQuery sequences using json:to-array()
- construct objects from maps using xdmp:to-json()

<del>This code returns the following JSON from your sample XML: `{"Catname":["Varname"]}`, which doesn't seem very useful. I'll update once you've added the output you want to see.</del>

Comment: Thanks. I've added the wanted output.

Answer (score 2):

You miss the context in the second for loop

You probably want to do something like this:

```
{
  for  $cat in distinct-values($doc//ns:category/@name) return (
    <json:value xsi:type="xs:string">
      {$cat}
    </json:value>
    <json:array>
      {for $var in $doc//ns:category[@name = $cat]//ns:variable/@name return <json:value>{$var}</json:value>}
    </json:array>
  )
}
```